# Limit of $\frac{(e^{\sin(z)} - 1)^3}{\sin(z) - z}$ as $z \to 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I thought about solving this woth L'Hopital's rule, but we never covered the rule for complex limits in class. I can't find a hidden derivative and writing everything out as polynomial also doesn't even feel like it's worth the time.

Comment: Hint: $\frac {e^{z}-1} z \to 1$ and $\frac {\sin z -z} {z^{3}}  \to -\frac 1 6$. $.

Comment: You can use L'Hospital's rule exactly in the same way as for real functions. Here I feel you will have to apply it several times in a row.

Comment: @geetha290krm I assume you used the sequence of sin(z) to find the result on the seconds limit. Are we always allowed to just devide the sequence by $z^3$, or any other number/variable if it's still well defined?

Comment: @Abezhiko I think that deriving it 1 time would give something that works but I am looking for a solution wthout L'Hopitals's rule since we didn't cover it.

Comment: `Limit[(Exp[Sin[z]] - 1)^3/(Sin[z] - z), z -> 0]`  -6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$L=\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{(e^{\sin(z)} - 1)^3}{\sin(z) - z}=\lim_{z \to 0} \left(\frac{e^{\sin z}-1}{\sin z}\right)^3\frac{\sin^3z}{\sin z-z}=\lim_{t \to 0} \left(\frac{e^{t}-1}{t}\right)^3  \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z^3+O(z^4)}{-z^3/6+ O(z^5)}$$
$$\implies L=-6$$